# DFA for even number of As, odd number of Bs and precisely one C

Tags: finite-automata

Exactly as the title says, I'm looking for a DFA for an even number of A, odd number of B, and exactly one C, can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: Does *every string* contain (an even number of A) AND (an odd number of B) AND (exactly one C)"? Or does your *language* contain strings with an even number of A, odd number of B, exactly one C?

Comment: Possible words include BC, CB, ABCA, BBACBA. Words that aren't in the language are: B, A, ABBA, ACABB. So it doesn't have to require A AND B

Comment: According to your examples it looks like every string contain an even number of A AND an odd number of B AND exactly one C.

Answer (score 1):

Divide and conquer. You could design a DFA over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{A,B,C\}$

- for an even number of A, call it $M_1$
- for an odd number of B, call it $M_2$
- accepting exactly one C, call it $M_3$

Then design a new DFA equivalent to $M_1 \cap M_2 \cap M_3$ (by closure properties of regular languages).

Comment: In the language are CB, ABCA, BBACBA. Using ∩ wouldn't allow this would it?

Comment: @user103296 Yes, the intersection accepts these strings strings.

Answer (score 1):

A common idiom for problems like this is to use the states to remember what has been seen so far: are there an even number of A's or not; are there an even number of B's or not; are there 0, 1, 2 or more C's?

For example, having seen the input ABAABCA, we would be in state (even A's, even B's, 1 C) and then if we see an A we would pass to state (odd A's, even B's, 1 C). I'll leave it to you to determine which of the twelve states should be the start and which should be the final state.

Comment: That makes sense thank you, do you possibly know how I would be able to turn my problem into a regular expression in order to make an NFA?

Comment: @user103296 The question asks about making  DFA.  Why are you then asking about regular expressions?  Regular expressions ([Type-3 grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#Type-3_grammars)) are much more restrictive than those which can be processed by a DFA (Type-0 grammars)

Comment: I was taught to start with a regular expression, then make a NFA, then convert that to a DFA.

Comment: @user103296 Well, that works. So does this. *puts on sensei outfit* There are many paths to the top of the mountain, Grasshopper.

Comment: @cort: a DFA is not the same as a Turing machine. The language it recognizes is certainly regular.

Comment: @CortAmmon actually, NFAs, DFAs and (vanilla) regexes have the same power